# Duplicate key error with Richfaces 4 on glassfish when deploying EAR

Tags: jakarta-ee, richfaces, glassfish-3, ear, netbeans7.0

Hi i have this error when i try to deploy my ear.
My ear as an war and an ejb.
If i deploy only the ejb and after the war it's work.

- Config :
- Netbeans 7.0.1
- Glassfish 3.1.1
- Db2
- EclipseLink (JPA 2)

  Lib

  - PDFClown
  - commons-beanutils-1.8.3
  - commons-codec-1.5
  - commons-digester-2.0
  - commonslang-2.4
  - commons-logging-1.1.1
  - commons-net-ftp-2.0
  - cssparser-0.9.5
  - jhighlight-1.0
  - json
  - jstatcom
  - log4j-1.2.15
  - lucene-analyzers-3.0.2
  - lucene-core-3.0.2
  - lucene-snowball-3.0.3
  - prettyfaces-jsf3-3.3.0
  - primefaces-3.0.2M2
  - sac-1.3
  - velocity-1.5
  - guava-r09
  - commons-fileupload-1.2.2
  - common-io-2.0.1
  - commons-collections-3.2.1
  - richfaces-copmponents-api-4.0.0
  - richfaces-copmponents-ui-4.0.0
  - richfaces-core-api-4.0.0
  - richfaces-core-ui-4.0.0

No sources in WEBINF/lib/

```
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! duplicate key: interface javax.validation.constraints.AssertTrue
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:375)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:225)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:4750)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:550)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5366)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2000)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1651)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:294)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:462)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:382)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1064)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1244)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1232)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:209)
at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:238)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the ear deployment deployed the library twice:
richfaces-components-ui-X.x.x.jar
And inside in /META-INF/csv.xml is load twice and make the  problem of duplication key.

I find a solution is to remove search lib on the ear.

Just add this line in the application.xml of the ear : 
**< library-directory />**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application version="6" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd">
  <display-name>ez-ear</display-name>
  <module>
    <ejb>ejb.jar</ejb>    
  </module>  
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>web.war</web-uri>
    <context-root/>      
    /web>
  </module>  
  <library-directory />
</application>
```

Comment: hi, my problem is https://community.jboss.org/thread/221694. can you please look into it . I tried your solution but its giving ClassNotFoundExceptions for that java files i have in ejb module . any idea ?